# How do I 'foreach' through a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a two-dimensional array,

```
string[,] table = {
                       { "aa", "aaa" },
                       { "bb", "bbb" }
                   };
```

And I'd like to `foreach` through it like this,

```
foreach (string[] row in table)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[0] + " " + row[1]);
}
```

But, I get the error:

> Can't convert type string to string[]

Is there a way I can achieve what I want, i.e. iterate through the first dimension of the array with the iterator variable returning me the one-dimensional array for that row?

Comment: Hint: string[,] != string[][]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you define your array like this:

```
string[][] table = new string[][] {
                       new string[] { "aa", "aaa" },
                       new string[]{ "bb", "bbb" }
};
```

Then you can use a foreach loop on it.

Comment: ...because then it's an array of an array.  That also means your arrays could be jagged.

Comment: This is not a 2D array. It's an array in an array. Which works as well as using a normal array, in a class that has getters and setters with X and Y parameters and that uses the x*width+y formula.

Comment: Don't use `foreach` - use nested `for` loops, one for each dimension of the array.

Comment: No explanation or example for `foreach` + wrong way

Answer (score 86):

Multidimensional arrays aren't enumerable. Just iterate the good old-fashioned way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(table[i, 0] + " " + table[i, 1]);
}
```

Comment: A small point:  multidimensional arrays *are* enumerable, just not in the way the OP wants.

Comment: Ok, @Odrade, I'll grant you that.

Comment: Actually does what OP wants and therefore the best answer. (Although only in the "do what I want not what I asked for" sense!)

Answer (score 40):

As others have suggested, you could use nested for-loops or redeclare your multidimensional array as a jagged one.

However, I think it's worth pointing out that multidimensional arrays *are* enumerable, just not in the way that you want.  For example:

```
string[,] table = {
                      { "aa", "aaa" },
                      { "bb", "bbb" }
                  };

foreach (string s in table)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

/* Output is:
  aa
  aaa
  bb
  bbb
*/
```

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE**: I had some time on my hands, so ... I went ahead and fleshed out this idea. See below for the code.

---

Here's a bit of a crazy answer:

You *could* do what you're looking for -- essentially treat a two-dimensional array as a table with rows -- by writing a static method (perhaps an extension method) that takes a `T[,]` and returns an `IEnumerable<T[]>`. This would require copying each "row" of the underlying table into a new array, though.

A perhaps better (though more involved) approach would be to actually write a class that implements `IList<T>` as a wrapper around a single "row" of a two-dimensional array (you would probably set `IsReadOnly` to true and just implement the getter for the `this[int]` property and probably `Count` and `GetEnumerator`; everything else could throw a `NotSupportedException`). Then your static/extension method could return an `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` and provide deferred execution.

That way you could write code pretty much like what you have:

```
foreach (IList<string> row in table.GetRows()) // or something
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[0] + " " + row[1]);
}
```

Just a thought.

---

Implementation suggestion:

```
public static class ArrayTableHelper {
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> GetRows<T>(this T[,] table) {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); ++i)
            yield return new ArrayTableRow<T>(table, i);
    }

    private class ArrayTableRow<T> : IList<T> {
        private readonly T[,] _table;
        private readonly int _count;
        private readonly int _rowIndex;

        public ArrayTableRow(T[,] table, int rowIndex) {
            if (table == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("table");

            if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= table.GetLength(0))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowIndex");

            _table = table;
            _count = _table.GetLength(1);
            _rowIndex = rowIndex;
        }

        // I didn't implement the setter below,
        // but you easily COULD (and then set IsReadOnly to false?)
        public T this[int index] {
            get { return _table[_rowIndex, index]; }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public int Count {
            get { return _count; }
        }

        bool ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
            for (int i = 0; i < _count; ++i)
                yield return this[i];
        }

        // omitted remaining IList<T> members for brevity;
        // you actually could implement IndexOf, Contains, etc.
        // quite easily, though
    }
}
```

...now I think I should give StackOverflow a break for the rest of the day ;)

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how you define your multi-dimensional array. Here are two options:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // First
            string[,] arr1 = {
                       { "aa", "aaa" },
                       { "bb", "bbb" }
                   };

            // Second
            string[][] arr2 = new[] {
                new[] { "aa", "aaa" },
                new[] { "bb", "bbb" }
            };

            // Iterate through first
            for (int x = 0; x <= arr1.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
                for (int y = 0; y <= arr1.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
                    Console.Write(arr1[x, y] + "; ");

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            // Iterate through second second
            foreach (string[] entry in arr2)
                foreach (string element in entry)
                    Console.Write(element + "; ");

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple extension method that returns each row as an `IEnumerable<T>`. This has the advantage of not using any extra memory:

```
public static class Array2dExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rows<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        for (int r = array.GetLowerBound(0); r <= array.GetUpperBound(0); ++r)
            yield return row(array, r);
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> row<T>(T[,] array, int r)
    {
        for (int c = array.GetLowerBound(1); c <= array.GetUpperBound(1); ++c)
            yield return array[r, c];
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    string[,] siblings = { { "Mike", "Amy" }, { "Mary", "Albert" }, {"Fred", "Harry"} };

    foreach (var row in siblings.Rows())
        Console.WriteLine("{" + string.Join(", ", row) + "}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ you can do it like this:

```
var table_enum = table

    // Convert to IEnumerable<string>
    .OfType<string>()

    // Create anonymous type where Index1 and Index2
    // reflect the indices of the 2-dim. array
    .Select((_string, _index) => new {
        Index1 = (_index / 2),
        Index2 = (_index % 2), // ← I added this only for completeness
        Value = _string
    })

    // Group by Index1, which generates IEnmurable<string> for all Index1 values
    .GroupBy(v => v.Index1)

    // Convert all Groups of anonymous type to String-Arrays
    .Select(group => group.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray());

// Now you can use the foreach-Loop as you planned
foreach(string[] str_arr in table_enum) {
    // …
}
```

This way it is also possible to use the foreach for looping through the columns instead of the rows by using Index2 in the GroupBy instead of Index 1. If you don't know the dimension of your array then you have to use the GetLength() method to determine the dimension and use that value in the quotient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big fan of this method because of the memory usage involved, but if you use the arrays it produces, it isn't such a waste.

```
public static void ForEachRow<T>(this T[,] list, Action<int, T[]> action)
{
    var len = list.GetLength(0);
    var sub = list.GetLength(1);

    T[] e;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        e = new T[sub];

        for (j = 0; j < sub; j++)
        {
            e[j] = list[i, j];
        }

        action(i, e);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
var list = new[,]{0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8};

list.ForEachRow((i, row) =>
{
    for (var j = 0; j < row.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]: {2}", i, j, row[j]);
    }
});
```

The other solution I found is less memory intensive, but will use more CPU, especially when the dimensions of the arrays' entries are larger.

```
public static void ForEachRow<T>(this T[,] list, Action<int, IEnumerable<T>> action)
{
    var len = list.GetLength(0);
    var sub = list.GetLength(1);

    int i, j;
    IEnumerable<T> e;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        e = Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        for (j = 0; j < sub; j++)
        {
            e = e.Concat(AsEnumerable(list[i, j]));
        }

        action(i, e);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(T add)
{
    yield return add;
}
```

Implementation:

```
var list = new[,]{0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8};

list.ForEachRow((i, row) =>
{
    var j = 0;

    forrach (var o in row)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]: {2}", i, j, o);

        ++j;
    }
});
```

As a whole, I find the first option to be more intuitive, especially if you want to access the produced array by its indexer.

At the end of the day, this is all just eye candy, neither methods should really be used in favour of directly accessing the source array;

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    foreach (var j = 0; j < list.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]: {2}", i, j, list[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a multi-dimensional array is like a table.  You don't have an *x* element and a *y* element for each entry; you have a string at (for instance) `table[1,2]`.

So, each entry is still only one string (in your example), it's just an entry at a specific x/y value.  So, to get both entries at `table[1, x]`, you'd do a nested for loop.  Something like the following (not tested, but should be close)

```
for (int x = 0; x < table.Length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < table.Length; y += 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", table[x, y], table[x, y + 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[][] languages = new string[2][];
            languages[0] = new string[2];
            languages[1] = new string[3];
// inserting data into double dimensional arrays.
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                languages[0][i] = "Jagged"+i.ToString();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                languages[1][j] = "Jag"+j.ToString();
            }

// doing foreach through 2 dimensional arrays.
foreach (string[] s in languages)
            {
                foreach (string a in s)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this. I hope to help. It work with

```
static void Main()
    {
        string[,] matrix = {
                               { "aa", "aaa" },
                               { "bb", "bbb" }
                           };
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string element in matrix)
        {
            if (index < matrix.GetLength(1))
            {
                Console.Write(element);
                if (index < (matrix.GetLength(1) - 1))
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                index++;
            }
            if (index == matrix.GetLength(1))
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
                index = 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doable but hacky. Extending on Odrade's answer:

```
string[,] table = { { "aa", "aaa" }, { "bb", "bbb" } };
bool eol = false;
foreach (string s in table) {
    if (eol) Console.WriteLine(" " + s);
    else Console.Write(s);
    eol = !eol;
}
```

I would argue, though, that foreach is suitable where the index doesn't matter in which case the for solution of Marcelo Cantos is what you'd want.