# Assign values to 2D array

Tags: c#

I need to assign values to 2D array but I can't find the right syntax.
I tried this but is't wrong:

```
string[][] s2d = new string[][] {
  {"val1","val2"},
  {"val1bis","val2bis"}
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want array of arrays so declare array of arrays

```
string[][] s2d = new string[][] {
  new string[] {"val1","val2"},
  new string[] {"val1bis","val2bis"}
};
```

Answer (score 8):

You are almost there, just change the [`convention`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) and use `[,].`, `[][]` used to define Array of arrays (`Jagged` arrays).

```
string[,] s2d = new string[,] {
  {"val1","val2"},
  {"val1bis","val2bis"}
};
```

If you want to enumerate on Multidimensional arrays you can do that but it is a flatten array.

```
foreach(var s in s2d) 
{
    // logic
}
```

Just access the elements in traditional way (if want).

```
for(int i=0;i < s2d.GetLength(0);i++)
    for(int j=0;j < s2d .GetLength(1);j++)
        var val = s2d [i,j];
```

Comment: My problem is the next foreach. See comment below. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using an incorrect syntax:

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: I need to use in a foreach: `foreach (string[] s in sd2){}`. With string[,] is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want a 2d  array

```
string[,] s2d = new string[2,2] { {"val1","val2"}, {"val1bis","val2bis"}};
```

string[][] gives you a possibility of a jagged array

Comment: I need to use in a foreach: `foreach (string[] s in sd2){}`. With string[,] is not working.

Comment: so you didnt want a array of 2d, you wanted a jagged array of any number of arrays.. thats a big difference

Comment: Yes, sort of. What I need, at the end, is a fast way to define a set of values on which do some operations: I need to create a bunch of nodes in an XML, and I use s[0]=nodeName and s[1]=value. The array-of-array is the fastest way i got to write code without replication.

Comment: Well this way you would use foreach ( string[2] s in sd2) which would give you s[0] and s[1]

Comment: it doesn't work. I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834233/how-to-foreach-through-a-2-dimensional-array) with the same solution using `string[][]`